# How to convert 1692.75 to 1.69e+03 in C?

Tags: c, casting

I'm just beginning and I don't know how to change floating point form to  exponential form.

Comment: And you've really exhausted all reasonable means of finding any kind of help with this problem? Books, internet search, manuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A float is a float and has no other representation other than it's binary representation in memory. But you can change the way you print it to the console.

This can be done by specifying it in the `printf` function. 
see [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

What you need is `printf("%.2e",myfloat)`

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, my mistake. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Those two "numbers" are simply the result of *formatting* the same floating point number in two different ways.  No number conversion or casting is involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about internal representation - don't worry, it's all the same under the hood.

If you are going to print `x = 1692.75` in desired form, use `printf("%2.2e\n", x);`

Comment: Try bonnet - We cobbled the language. God know what happened on those boats!

Comment: @EdHeal What do you mean?

Comment: This side of the pond we speak English. Do not not what language you speak in the US. The dictionary must have got thrown overboard on the May flower or at the tea party.

Comment: @EdHeal, are you sure you are speaking English now? I'm neither American nor the UK citizen, but I still can tell that your pure-ish efforts are full of typos end errata. By the way, `bonnet` is commonly referred to in the context of car stuff, while `under the hood` has a general meaning of things' intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

They are one of the same thing.

If you wish to print it see the manual page for printf

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the internal representation of the float, which is binary and has nothing to do with what you see when you print the value.

If you just want to print your float you can you the `printf`family of functions:

```
printf("%.2e", 1692.75);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Test yourself is it working or not?